# How to set up a Static IP on Raspberry Pi 5 with Raspbian - dhcpcd.conf missing

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, dhcp, static-ip, pi-5

I am trying to set up a static IP lease on Raspberry Pi 5. The `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file does not exist and dhcpcd is not installed. Following the latest guides does not work. I ideally don't need to use DHCP, but if there's a way that works with either option I'm open to suggestions.

I'm starting to wonder whether the Pi 5 been set up correctly.

I am unable to install any packages since I do not have internet. Is there any long lasting method that could work?

Comment: Use `sudo nmcli dev wifi connect <network-ssid>` or with password protection `sudo nmcli dev wifi connect <network-ssid> password <network-password>` or do that without showing the password with `sudo nmcli --ask dev wifi connect <network-ssid>`. Or use the graphic option `sudo nmtui`.

Comment: I'm surprised the usual crew didn't jump on the use of "Raspbian" which hasn't existed for over 3 years :p

Comment: @JaromandaX haha! I haven't used RasPi OS in years, I didn't know it had changed name.

Comment: Does anyone read the details of the release [bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/)  before posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a useful guide, Raspberry Pi OS is basically Debian, with Bookwork being largely the same as the Debian Bookworm release. This guide was helpful for me. - https://itslinuxfoss.com/set-up-static-ip-address-debian-12-linux/

Comment: It would be good if you added a brief summary of what you did based on the guide in order to avoid a conflict with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538).

Answer (score 6):

I see you've found an answer, so this is just FYI:

The people who run the RPi manufacturing operation decided to replace `dhcpcd` with `nmcli` as the ***default*** DHCP client program for the **bookworm** release. However, as I understand it, `dhcpcd` remains in the distribution (or certainly available for the price of a `sudo apt install dhcpcd`), so you can continue to use it - at least for a while.

And since this is an *"FYI"* kind of answer, I'll *opine* that `dhcpcd` is a pretty good DHCP client. It's still [actively maintained by Roy Marples](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd), and recently upgraded to ver 10. I feel that part of the reason that `dhcpcd` fell out of favor with the RPi manufacturing consortium was that they (and Debian) let it languish... they decided to stick with version 8 instead of following the upstream releases. Why?... I don't know, you'll have to ask them.

If you decide you do want to stick with `dhcpcd`, you have a couple of options:

1. Stick with the *old-ish* version 8.1.2.
2. If you want the latest version (ver 10) you'll need to [build it from source](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/blob/master/BUILDING.md).

Finally, wrt to your comment, *"I'm starting to wonder whether the Pi 5 been set up correctly."*. Yeah - you're not alone. :)

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer. Really helpful. Hopefully RPi can sort this out and we can all get back to the normal issues with networking!

Comment: You're welcome. One question out of curiosity: your question said *"dhcpcd is not installed"*. Can you confirm that? I recall reading that the RPi folks were going to leave `dhcpcd` in the distro, but disable it (maybe you have to use `raspi-config` to enable. it??)

Comment: They did not "replace dhcpcd with nmcli" - "they" adopted NetworkManager (used by most distos) which has a CLI interface `nmcli`

Comment: @Milliways: When a ***default*** software tool/service is changed by the owners of the software distro, I call that a ***replacement***. You can call it whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The first Raspberry Pi OS that supports Raspberry Pi 5 manages the network settings by default with NetworkManager, as per https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/

To set a static IP of 192.168.1.50:

```
$ nmcli connection modify help
[...]
Examples:
nmcli con mod em1-1 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addr "192.168.1.2/24, 10.10.1.5/8"

$ nmcli con show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa  ethernet  eth0   
MyWiFi              bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb  wifi      wlan0  
lo                  cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc  loopback  lo     

$ nmcli con show "Wired connection 1" | tee original_network_settings.txt

$ sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.method manual ipv4.addr 192.168.1.50/24
```